# How to turn 2 arrays into an object with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, loops, object, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an object which contains 2 objects with properties:

```
const objects = {
  Battery: {
    batteryDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'type', 'part_no'],
    batteryDetailsVal: [
      'HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC',
      'Extended Range',
      '4P94-Q051',
    ],
  },
  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'part_no', 'Cell Count'],
    moduleDetailsVal: [
      '8367532735006109322258160 50',
      'LJ98-10C779-A51',
      '32',
      '6',
    ],
  },
};
```

I need to change the structure of the data to this:

```
const desiredObject = {
  Battery: {
    'serial_no': 'HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC',
    'type': 'Extended Range',
    'part_no': '4P94-Q051',
  },
  Modules: {
    'serial_no':'8367532735006109322258160 50',
    'part_no':'LJ98-10C779-A51',
    'cell_count': '32',
  },
};
```

I have tried

```
let emptyObject = {}

Object.keys(objects).forEach((q, i) => {
    emptyObject = {
        objects[q] 
    }
})
```

but isn't quite achieving what i want, any help is welcome. Thanks

EDIT:

I just realised that for moduleDetailsVal sometimes the value is an array of arrays like this:

```
const objectsWithMultipleArrays = {
  Battery: {
    batteryDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'type', 'part_no'],
    batteryDetailsVal: [
      'HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC',
      'Extended Range',
      '4P94-Q051',
    ],
  },
  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'part_no', 'Cell Count'],
    moduleDetailsVal: [
    [
        "8367532735006109322258162 53",
        "LJ98-10C779-A54",
        "28",
    ],
    [
        "8367532735006109322258163 54",
        "LJ98-10C779-A55",
        "27",
    ],
    [
        "8367532735006109322258163 56",
        "LJ98-10C779-A56",
        "27"
    ]
],
  },
};
```

The desire is now for that object to have an array of objects like this

```
const newDesiredObject = {
  Battery: {
    serial_no: "HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC",
    type: "Extended Range",
    part_no: "4P94-Q051"
  },
  "Modules": [
    {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 50",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A51",
      "cell_count": "32"
    },
     {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 51",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A52",
      "cell_count": "33"
    },
     {
      "serial_no": "8367532735006109322258160 52",
      "part_no": "LJ98-10C779-A53",
      "cell_count": "33"
    },

  ]
}
```

Please advise how i can handle this case

Comment: Are you also expecting the answer to convert `"Cell Count"` to `"cell_count"` or was it originally supposed to be `"cell_count"`?

Comment: yes @NickParsons, sorry that was oversight on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that:

- Both arrays will always have equal lengths. OR
- Keys' array (Array 1) is bigger and you want all the keys from Array 1 and all excess keys will have value `undefined`. OR
- Keys' array (Array 1) is smaller and you want to skip all the extra values present in the values' array (Array 2).

You can try the below code, I have used [Array reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on array 1 and used the `index` parameter to access the corresponding value in array 2. For looping the `objects` object I have used `Object.keys()` and created a new desired object.

So the complete answer for your problem will be something like below:

```js
const objects = {
  Battery: {
    batteryDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "type", "part_no"],
    batteryDetailsVal: ["HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC", "Extended Range", "4P94-Q051"],
  },
  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "part_no", "Cell Count"],
    moduleDetailsVal: ["8367532735006109322258160 50", "LJ98-10C779-A51", "32", "6"],
  },
};

function twoArraysToObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    obj[item] = arr2[index];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

const desiredObject = {};
Object.keys(objects).forEach((key) => {
  const keyNamesArr = Object.keys(objects[key]);
  desiredObject[key] = twoArraysToObject(objects[key][keyNamesArr[0]], objects[key][keyNamesArr[1]]);
});

console.log(desiredObject);
```

Comment: In the question, both arrays for `Modules` don't have the same length (but I'm not sure if this impacts the answer ever)

Comment: But in desired object extra value is left from array 2, so my answer should work when `array1.length <= array2.length`.

Comment: Yeah, I think your code is fine, just the first statement "assuming both arrays will have the same length always" isn't an assumption we can make as we can see that in the answer that isn't always the case (so I was mainly just making a comment about the statement, not your code) :)

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify the assumptions, Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: @ShivamSharma can you please update the code so that it handles multiple `moduleDetailsVal` like this 

  Modules: {
    moduleDetailsKey: ["serial_no", "part_no", "Cell Count"],
    moduleDetailsVal: [
       ["8367532735006109322258160 50", "LJ98-10C779-A51", "32", "6"],
       ["8367532735006109322258160 51", "LJ98-10C779-A52", "33", "7"],
       ["8367532735006109322258160 52", "LJ98-10C779-A53", "34", "8"]
    ],
  },

Comment: What will be the output then? You should update the question or add an updated part at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the entries of your `objects` object to get an array of key value pairs. You can then map this array of key value pairs so that each each value is updated to have a new object. This new object can be built using `Object.fromEntries()` and mapping the array found at the key ending with `"DetailsKey"` to an array of another set of key-value pairs, where each value is the associated value from the array at the key ending with `"DetailsVal"` (we can use the index `i` to grab the corresponding item). You can then wrap your mapped `objects`'s entries in another call to `Object.fromEntries()`, which will build an object for you from your new key-value pair array:

```js
const objects = { Battery: { batteryDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'type', 'part_no'], batteryDetailsVal: [ 'HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC', 'Extended Range', '4P94-Q051', ], }, Modules: { moduleDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'part_no', 'cell_count'], moduleDetailsVal: [ '8367532735006109322258160 50', 'LJ98-10C779-A51', '32', '6', ], }, };

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objects).map(([key, value]) => {
  const innerEntries = Object.entries(value);
  const [, details] = innerEntries.find(([key]) => key.endsWith("DetailsKey"));
  const [, vals] = innerEntries.find(([key]) => key.endsWith("DetailsVal"));
  return [key, Object.fromEntries(details.map((key, i) => [key, vals[i]]))];
}));
console.log(res);
```

If you're ok with relying on the object property/value order the `Object.value()` gives you (which has only recently been standardized) then you could remove the `.find()` calls and grab your keys using indexes:

```js
const objects = { Battery: { batteryDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'type', 'part_no'], batteryDetailsVal: [ 'HJ3CA19347410218LJ98 151 QC', 'Extended Range', '4P94-Q051', ], }, Modules: { moduleDetailsKey: ['serial_no', 'part_no', 'cell_count'], moduleDetailsVal: [ '8367532735006109322258160 50', 'LJ98-10C779-A51', '32', '6', ], }, };

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objects).map(([key, value]) => {
  const [details, vals] = Object.values(value);
  return [key, Object.fromEntries(details.map((key, i) => [key, vals[i]]))];
}));
console.log(res);
```